# How to pin an UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout section

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, sections, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I have a CollectionView and I'm using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout to manage its layout. I have 6 sections, and each one can make horizontal scroll. I navigate on CollectionView scrolling vertical. The problem is that I want to pin the entire first section, so when I scroll down the first section stays pinned on the top of the CollectionView.
I've found that it can be possible with pinToVisibleBounds property but it only pins the header. There is a possible way to archive it? Can I insert an entire section inside the header to get the pinToVisibleBounds property?

Thank you very much.

I've tried to use pinToVisibleBounds property but it only pins the header.

Comment: Why don't you use two different collection views? One for the section you want to be pinned, and another one for the rest to be scrolled.

Comment: I've thought that but I think if I can make it  all in one collection view it will have better performace and if I do this the bounce effect would look strange."